# Star-shaped domain whose closure is not homeomorphic to $B^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A star-shaped (relative to $0$) domain $U$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each $x \in U$, the line segment from $0$ to $x$ lies entirely in $U$.

Is there a star-shaped domain whose closure $\bar{U}$ is not homeomorphic to $B^n$(the unit $n$-ball)?

Comment: your definition of a star shaped subset is highly nonstandard

Comment: @ooo I apologize for my casualness. maybe I should give it another name..

Comment: Note the closure of a star-shaped domain is also star-shaped.

Comment: @DanielRust can you elaborate on this?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more i'm not sure the above statement is very useful for this problem. I shall leave it in any case as it is true.

Comment: @DanielRust It's not even true if we take the definition from the OP (which requires openness). Otherwise $U=[0,1]\times\{0\}^{n-1}$ would be a pretty simple solution to the problem.

Comment: I don't understand the problem @roman. A star-shaped domain is open (that's the 'domain' part of the name in so far as I understand the OP's writing) and a subspace being star-shaped doesn't a priori require the openness condition - only the 'contracting point' condition (which up to translation is equivalent to $0$ being the contracting point).

Comment: I see @daniel, I didn't see the difference between star-shaped domain and subspace and just assumed the OP was using a non-standard definition for the latter one (i.e. requirering openness).

Comment: Well, it's just a star-shaped open subset around $0$. I didn't expect my writing could be so confusing. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @000 Is it...? That's the definition I have, too. At least the word "highly" is not a good choice. That's the definition one can find in Spivak's "Calculus on manifolds."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff:I am afraid to say yes. And in three things: bounded, open, containing 0. I have taken a look at standard books (Spanier, Munkres, Lang (Complex analysis), Conway (Complex analysis)) and they all offer the wiki definition. I doubt you can find more than 2 standard books offering your definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem the answer is yes.  Let $U$ be the region bounded by a topologist's sine curve wrapped once around the origin in the plane. I.e. take $$U := \{re^{it}: r<2+\sin(\frac{-\pi^2}{t})\} \\ 0<t \leq 2\pi$$

and note that the topological boundary is not locally path connected.

http://tinyurl.com/org9vkl

**Edit**:  I realized a previous definition of the curve did not result in an open set (points of $U$ on the positive real axis were not in the interior).  This was fixed by requiring the curve to have minimal norm ($=1$) at $t= 2\pi$.  This results in more points in the boundary than are in the image of the curve (the closure also contains an interval on the positive real axis), but the boundary still fails to be locally path connected.